# Laptop using WiFi but VirtualBox doesn't use WiFi

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Oracle VirtualBox on Win 10.
[http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_software_setup/#network-configuration]
I am stuck at this step because as I described in the title, I am using wifi on my laptop but in virtualbox, it detects 'ethernet' instead.

The ideal scenario: Laptop uses WiFi, Ubuntu, Master has wlan0 to communicate with my SBC, Raspberry Pi. Slave.

Do I need to install a Wifi driver in ubuntu to make this work?

I tried changing the network configuration in the VirtualBox, tried changing network connection from Bridge to NAT etc and it still doesn't work. I have been stuck at this part for a long while, please kindly help me out.

P.S I am trying just to move the LIDAR sensor.

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280729/laptop-using-wifi-but-virtualbox-doesn%27t-use-wifi./) by [Bbybo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/33285/bbybo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
This question seems rather off-topic for this support forum.

@Bbybo93: in the end you'll probably use ROS, but I would recommend you ask this on a different forum, such as the VirtualBox support forum or AskUbuntu or the appropriate Stack Overflow forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is here. It is true that Virtualbox calls it's internet connection "Ethernet", but it will still be using the Wi-Fi from your laptop. You should still be able to ping anyone on your Wi-Fi and connect to them the same way that tutorial explains.

All Virtualbox does is port whatever internet connection you have and send it over to your Virtual Machine and calls it "ethernet", even if it's not an actual ethernet connection.

---

Originally posted by [JamesDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30501/jamesdoe/) with karma: 78 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0